# Ngx-Formly two inputs in one custom type

Tags: html, css, angular, ngx-formly, mat-form-field

Is there a way to define a custom formly type with two inputs at once without the black line coming from material.

What i need is a formly number input with a slider. The user should be able to normally type in the input and change the given value. 

Something like this: 
 
[image]

My approach:

Extending the custom component in my `FormlyModule.forRoot({types:[...]})` :

```ts
{
    name: 'custom-test-input',
    component: FormlyTestInputComponent, 
    extends:'input',
}
```

The template:

```html
<input matInput 
  type="number"
  [formControl]="formControl" 
/>
<mat-slider></mat-slider>
```

I know how to bind both values using `to.bindValue`(not in the sample code above) but after extending ***input*** i have this this input field line located under my whole form-field which i think is coming from `mat-form-field`. 
Like:

[image]

Is there a way to shrink this line, put it under the input field and **keep** this in one custom type? Thank you for help!

Comment: Hi , Can you tell me how to bind two form elements in single template?

Comment: @Ranjith have a look at fieldGroups. Is something like this what you are looking for?: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-field-group-required-6ukram?file=src%2Fapp%2Faddress%2Findex.ts

Comment: No. I need to create one `custom-mat-toggle` type form element where I should show `mat-slide-toggle` along with `mat-input`. Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Maybe I have a slider example here for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brfkcx-wixvhr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts (reload the page if you see `turbo_modules/zone.js error`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to hide the **mat-form-field-underline** after having a look on the implementation.
Using the defaultOptions which can be set on a custom form in the types array to access the hideFieldUnderline attribute(boolean) was the solution. 
 This is how you disable the Underline on a form which extends the custom form.

```
types: [{ 
    name: 'custom-slider-input',
    component: FormlyCustomSliderInputComponent, 
    extends:'slider',
    defaultOptions: {
        templateOptions: {
            hideFieldUnderline: true, //is hiding underline
        },
    }
}],
```

Comment: here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brfkcx-wixvhr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts (reload the page if you see `turbo_modules/zone.js error`).